# AKS System Node Pool and number of nodes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

The AKS docs mention that 3 nodes are recommended in Production for System Node Pool.

What is the rationale behind this?

Does the fact that the cluster is a private cluster change anything in the recommendation?